# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto', Python 3.9, PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pycrypto, pycryptodome

```
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I am using PyCharm Community 2020.3 and Python 3.9.

This project previously compiled and ran, but I had to replace the computer and re-create my development environment, and at that point, the project failed as above.

I re-installed pycryptodome (see picture), but still getting error.

Something is causing the compiler to not take note of pycryptodome being there.  Maybe something else is eclipsing it?  Do I need to uninstall the library "crypto"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try checking using - pip3 freeze to list the installed libraries just in case you are using virtual environment to verify

Comment: @Shreyashbhatt - `pip3 freeze` doesn't show anything when I run in DOS shell.  But in Pycharm it shows aes==1.0.0
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
crypto==1.4.1
idna==2.10
multipledispatch==0.6.0
Naked==0.1.31
pycryptodome==3.9.9
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.25.1
shellescape==3.8.1
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.26.2

Comment: @madzohan - It gave me a helpful idea.  I'll post as answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I followed @madzohan link.

- uninstall `crypto`.  I had installed this because I followed PyCharm's suggestion.
- uninstall `pycryptodome`
- re-install `pycryptodome`

I was able to run my script no problem.

Comment: this works for me.